# Adding Fullstory Android SDK fails on app build

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, ionic-framework, fullstory

I have an Android app built using Ionic/Capacitor/ReactJS. When I add the FullStory Android SDK and enable the plugin in gradle my file like this:

```
...

apply plugin: 'fullstory'

fullstory {
    org "[REDACTED]
    enabledVariants "debug"
    logLevel "debug"
    logcatLevel "debug"
}
```

I am now faced with an error on build:

```
> Task :app:fullstoryDebug
Applying FullStory to variant 'debug'...
FullStory: Detected framework OkHttp
FullStory: Detected framework Http(s)URLConnection
FullStory: Detected framework AndroidX Fragments
FullStory: Detected framework Capacitor

> Task :app:fullstoryDebug FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:fullstoryDebug'.
> Chunk [ margin–left: 10px] is not a valid entry
```

I have a third-party SDK in the app that I feel like might be causing the problem, I’m just not sure how to debug and find what is causing the CSS-looking “chunk” to be read by Fullstory and what makes it “invalid”.

The react app is very simple, just a hello-world app for the sake of narrowing down the issue.

Comment: I unzipped the vendor library AAR in question and found a matching string in the values.xml because the vendor has large HTML formatted content blocks in their strings. Had vendor remove the offending CSS string, then it moved down the chain to the next offending string in the same file. Ugh.

Working with Fullstory tech support at this point to see if we can somehow skip processing their values.xml files during their Gradle app instrumentation step.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post the answer we found after you contacted FullStory Support in case this comes up for any others.

This can be resolved by removing the space in-between any declarations. For example, if you had a declaration like this: `style=color:#00a652; font–size:16px;` you'd want that to instead be formatted like this: `style=color:#00a652;font–size:16px;`.

We'll also be working on an update on the FullStory side to handle this!